# Powershell UNC Path not supported exception

Tags: powershell, filepath, unc

Well I've struggled long enough with this one.  I have a project to compare two folders, one on each of two servers.  We are comparing files on the source server with those on the target server and will create a list of the files from the source that will need to be refreshed once an update is completed on the target server.

Here's my script (many thanks to http://quickanddirtyscripting.wordpress.com for the original) :

```
param ([string] $src,[string] $dst)

function get-DirHash()
{
    begin 
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
    }
    process 
    {
        dir -Recurse $_ | where { $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false -and ($_.Name -like "*.js" -or $_.Name -like "*.css"} | select Name,FullName,@{Name="SHA1 Hash"; Expression={get-hash $_.FullName -algorithm "sha1" }}
    }
    end 
    {
    }
}  

function get-hash 
{
    param([string] $file = $(throw 'a filename is required'),[string] $algorithm = 'sha256')
    try
    {
        $fileStream = [system.io.file]::openread((resolve-path $file));
        $hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::create($algorithm);
        $hash = $hasher.ComputeHash($fileStream);
        $fileStream.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        write-host $_
    }
    return $hash
}

Compare-Object $($src | get-DirHash) $($dst | get-DirHash) -property @("Name", "SHA1 Hash")
```

Now for some reason if I run this against local paths say `c:\temp\test1 c:\temp\test2` it works fine, but when I run it using `UNC` paths between two servers I get

> **Exception calling "OpenRead" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's format is not supported."**

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  The end result should be a list of files, but for some reason it doesn't like the `UNC` path.

The script name is `compare_js_css.ps1` and is called as such:

`.\compare_js_css.ps1 c:\temp\test1 c:\temp\test2`  <-- This works

`.\compare_js_css.ps1 \\\\devserver1\c$\websites\site1\website \\\\devserver2\c$\websites\site1\website`    <-- Returns the aforementioned exception.

Why?

Answer (score 7):

This gives the path you are after without the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::`:

```
(Resolve-Path $file).ProviderPath
```

No need to use a string replace.

Comment: Works great, but why do we need it?

Comment: I encourage you to consider @piers7 response below.

Answer (score 1):

`OpenRead` supports UNC paths. `Resolve-Path` returns you an object. Use `(Resolve-Path MyFile.txt).Path.Replace('Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::', '')` as the argument for `OpenRead`. The path returned from `Resolve-Path` when using UNC paths includes PowerShell's fully qualified schema which contains a header which is unsupported by the `OpenRead` method so it needs to be omitted.

Comment: Hmm... still get the same error.  I know it's not a permissions problem as well since I have admin access on both servers.

Comment: I get Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\ltlymanb\test1\style.min.css

Comment: Sry here is what I've been trying

.\compare_js_css.ps1 \\ltlymanb\c$\temp\test1 \\ltlymanb\c$\temp\test2

Comment: I've also run this and get the same.  

.\compare_js_css.ps1 \\ltlymanb\c$\websites\test\website \\c2devweb4\c$\websites\test\website

Comment: @BobLyman `OpenRead` doesn't support the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::` part of the path. You could do this: `(Resolve-Path $file).Path.Replace('Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::', '')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Convert-Path` cmdlet, which will provide you with the path in the 'regular' UNC form. This will be required any time you use any shell commands, or need to pass an entire path to a .Net method etc...

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156816.aspx